How do I host a Razor Classlib project in an ASP.NET MVC app and enable WebAssembly rendering?
I have two projects, one created with dotnet new mvc -o MvcWebApp, the other created with dotnet new razorclasslib -o RazorComponentLib.
I am trying to enable Server and WebAssembly rendering modes for a Razor Component contained inside the RazorComponentLib project.
Note that neither of these is a Blazor app, and my understanding is that they don't need to be? The docs suggest Razor Components should be able to render using WebAssembly on regular ASP.NET web apps.
I've added these sections to MvcWebApp/Program.cs
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

and
app.MapRazorComponents<Counter>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode();

but I cannot find any way to enable/activate the server and WebAssembly rendering. Components rendered using these modes just come out blank:
@using RazorComponentLib
<h2>Static:</h2>
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.Static))
<hr />
<h2>Server:</h2>
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.Server))
<hr />
<h2>Server Prerendered:</h2>
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
<hr />
<h2>WebAssembly:</h2>
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.WebAssembly))
<hr />
<h2>WebAssembly Prerendered:</h2>
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.WebAssemblyPrerendered))
<hr />


I've experimented with various different configurations and the furthest I get is something requesting _framework/dotnet.js and getting a 404 Not Found response - what am I missing here? What do I need to add to get my ASP.NET MVC project to host the _framework/dotnet.js components and support server and webassembly rendering models?
Full code for this example is at https://github.com/dylanbeattie/RazorComponentDemo
Thanks.


Note that neither of these is a Blazor app, and my understanding is that they don't need to be? The docs suggest Razor Components should be able to render using WebAssembly on regular ASP.NET web apps.

Blazor apps are regular ASP.NET web apps. Just like MVC apps are regular web apps. The same app can host both MVC, Razor Pages, and Blazor capabilities. In an ideal setup with all capabilities enabled, some routes would be served by controllers, others would be served by razor pages, while others would be served by Blazor.
In the GitHub sample, you appear to be trying to render the Razor Component from a regular Razor page as opposed to a Blazor page. While it is possible to make this work, I wouldn't recommend it.
With that out of your way, let's try and get your app working:
1. Static render mode
Your component updates its state based on user-input. This requires "interactivity". Since static render mode does not support it, this will not work for this component.
However, this render mode is useful for truly static components with interactivity. Your current setup will work as-is for those components.
2. Server & server pre-rendered

Update Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml to include the following line:
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<!-- add the following line: -->
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
<!-- -->
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)


In the project root, add a new App.razor file:
@* Placeholder App component just to make Blazor happy *@


In Program.cs, update MapRazorComponents<>() to use this new placeholder component:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
   .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();


In case a future component plans to make POST requests, you will also need to add the anti-forgery middleware in Program.cs:
app.UseAuthorization();
// add the following line:
app.UseAntiforgery();



Run the application and the server rendered counter components will now work.
3. Blazor Web Assembly and Web Assembly Pre-rendered
As of .NET 8, this is not supported within the MVC pipeline.
But you can get working this outside of the MVC pipeline.
Even within a Blazor context, it's not a very good idea to mix server & WebAssembly (even though this is supported) unless absolutely necessary.
A note on the razor library
The render mode is inconsequential to consumers of the razor library. If you're writing a library, your library will work for both wasm and server users. All your users need to know is whether a component in the library requires interactivity.

According to the Microsoft documentation, it seems that the two rendering modes you are looking for ("Server" and "WebAssembly") are only for the "Blazor" application. You should probably change the project to "Blazor".
Also, Microsoft has explained details about "Add Blazor support to an ASP.NET Core app".


Changes in Mvc App
In the project's layout file in MVC app Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
1- Add the following Component Tag Helper for a HeadOutlet component to the  markup after <base href="~/" />
<component type="typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.HeadOutlet)"
           render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

2- In the same page, add a  tag for the blazor.web.js script immediately before the Scripts render section
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

Changes in RazorComponentLib
Copy the following code and past it in _imports.razor page
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using RazorComponentLib

RenderMode.ServerPrerendered and RenderMode.Server are working as expected.
